# Case on Join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables data as below

```
table1:
Order    orderitem    value    
 O1       B-IV122       10
 O2       B-IV144       10     

table2:
order    Productionorder    productionitem    ProductionValue
 O1         P1               B-IV122               5
 O2         P2               B-IV111               6
 O2         P2               CCC144                6
 O2         P2               CCC000                4
```

Required Output:

```
  Order     Productionorder  orderitem   productionitem  value   ProductionValue
    O1         P1             B-IV122     B-IV122         10       5
    O2         P2             B-IV144     B-IV111         10       6
```

I tried with below code

```
select order,orderitem,Productionorder,productionitem,value ,ProductionValue  from 
(select order,orderitem,value from table1) t1
left outer join
(select Order,Productionorder,productionitem,ProductionValue from table2)t2
on t1.order = t2.order and t1.orderitem = t2.productionitem
```

MY query output:

```
 Order     Productionorder  orderitem   productionitem  value   ProductionValue
    O1         P1             B-IV122     B-IV122         10       5
    O2         P2             B-IV144     NULL            10       NULL
```

Instead of null,i want to take production item (B-IV111) which starts with 'B' and respective value..
(Note: I need to make a join with order and item too).Case is not working as expected.Can you please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain how these values: `B-IV144` and `B-IV111` are related?

Comment: In table2, user may maintain same or different item.if it is different, i need to take (B-IV111) item.

Comment: Is there any logic behind this or you want specifically B-IV111 in any case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.[order]
    ,orderitem
    ,value
    ,productionitem
    ,productionvalue
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.[order] = t2.[order]
    AND LEFT(t1.orderitem, 3) = LEFT(t2.productionitem, 3)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.. Its working...but can you please help me with left(item,3)..

Comment: For understanding

Comment: left(field,3) in plain words, tells the server to take the first 3 chars from the field (in our case orderitem)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an `inner join`:

```
select t1.order, t1.orderitem, t1.Productionorder, t2.productionitem, t1.value, t2.ProductionValue
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.order = t2.order and t1.orderitem = t2.productionitem;
```

The subqueries provide no value at all to the query, so I removed them.

EDIT:

You can use `outer apply` for your example:

```
select t1.order, t1.orderitem, t1.Productionorder,
       t2.productionitem, t1.value, t2.ProductionValue
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t1.order = t2.order 
      order by (case when t1.orderitem = t2.productionitem then 1 else 2 end)
     ) t2;
```

Note:  This works for the specific example in the question.  If your actual problem is more complicated, because there are multiple rows that match and that do not match, I would request that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, explanation, and a db/sql fiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: I posted an answer like this but deleted it when I noticed that last paragraph of the question asking for replacement for `NULL` values

Comment: @Gordon Linoff..thanks for the reply.If i make inner join, second record will not come in the results.

Comment: Thank you all for responding and providing suggestions.Thank you so much